# Rails using Facebook Like and Twitter Follow widgets with layout page with jQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, jquery-mobile, twitter

I have been battling to add the two widgets to my layout page (i.e. application.html.haml).

The first time the page loads they show up, then if I navigate to another page they don't show, so I thought I would write some JS to remove the script elements that load the respective SDKs, before running the boilerplate to call the SDK.

This works for the Twitter Follow widget, but not for the Facebook like.

My JS is below:

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {

    // Remove the Facebook and Twitter SDKs to force them to reload
    // Note: Located in head element, not div[data-role="page"]
    var $twitter_sdk = $('#twitter-wjs');
    var $facebook_sdk = $('#facebook-jssdk');

    // First time page is requested script tags won't exist
    if ($twitter_sdk.length) {
        $twitter_sdk.remove();
    }

    if ($facebook_sdk.length) {
        $facebook_sdk.remove();
    }

    // Facebook SDK
    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    // Twitter SDK
    ! function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
        if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
            js = d.createElement(s);
            js.id = id;
            js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }
    }(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

});
```

My HAML is here:

%div#home-page{:data => {:role => 'page'}}

```
    -# header
    %div.page-header{:data => {:role => 'header'}}
        %div.logo

    -# main content
    %div{:data => {:role => 'content'}}
        %div.shadow1box
            %img.shadow{:src => image_path('theme/shadow1.png'), :alt => 'shadow'}
        %div.content-padd

            %hr.ornamental
            %h3.home-title South Africa's premier business collaboration platform
            %hr.ornamental

            -# Search
            %form
                %div#main-search{:data => {:role => 'fieldcontain'}}
                    %input#search{:type => 'search', :name => 'search', :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Search site...'}

            -# Flash messages
            %div
                %p.notice
                    = notice
                %p.alert
                    = alert

            = yield :layout

            = render 'devise/shared/links'

            -# social
            %br
            %div.fb-follow{:data => {:href=> 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck', 'show-faces' => 'true', :width => '300'}}
            %br
            %br
            %a.twitter-follow-button{:href => 'https://twitter.com/KeepItLocal', :data => {'show-count' => 'false', :size => 'large'}}
                Follow @KeepItLocal


    -# footer
    %div{:data => {:role => 'footer'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, what I have done to work around this is as follows:

I placed the following in the body element, but outside of the jQM page (i.e it is present in the DOM, but not visible)

```
:javascript
    !function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)     [0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id))
{js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');

:javascript
    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

-# social
%div#social
    %br
    %div.fb-follow{:data => {:href=> 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck', 'show-faces' => 'true', :width => '300'}}
    %br
    %br
    %a.twitter-follow-button{:href => 'https://twitter.com/KeepItLocal', :data => {'show-count' => 'false', :size => 'large'}}
        Follow @KeepItLocal
```

I then wrote a bit of JS to clone #social and insert it into the page.

```
$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {

    $('#social').clone().appendTo('.ui-page-active #social-placeholder');

});
```

This then creates the desired effect. As an added bonus, on page changes the widgets appear immediately as opposed to taking a few seconds to load.

If someone  has a better solution please share.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {

```
// Remove the Facebook and Twitter SDKs to force them to reload
// Note: Located in head element, not div[data-role="page"]
var $twitter_sdk = $('#twitter-wjs');
var $facebook_sdk = $('#facebook-jssdk');

// First time page is requested script tags won't exist
if ($twitter_sdk.length) {
    $twitter_sdk.remove();
}

if ($facebook_sdk.length) {
    $facebook_sdk.remove();
}

// Facebook SDK
(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

// Twitter SDK
! function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
    if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = p + '://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }
}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
```

});
My HAML is here:

%div#home-page{:data => {:role => 'page'}}

```
-# header
%div.page-header{:data => {:role => 'header'}}
    %div.logo

-# main content
%div{:data => {:role => 'content'}}
    %div.shadow1box
        %img.shadow{:src => image_path('theme/shadow1.png'), :alt => 'shadow'}
    %div.content-padd

        %hr.ornamental
        %h3.home-title South Africa's premier business collaboration platform
        %hr.ornamental

        -# Search
        %form
            %div#main-search{:data => {:role => 'fieldcontain'}}
                %input#search{:type => 'search', :name => 'search', :autofocus => true, :placeholder => 'Search site...'}

        -# Flash messages
        %div
            %p.notice
                = notice
            %p.alert
                = alert

        = yield :layout

        = render 'devise/shared/links'

        -# social
        %br
        %div.fb-follow{:data => {:href=> 'https://www.facebook.com/zuck', 'show-faces' => 'true', :width => '300'}}
        %br
        %br
        %a.twitter-follow-button{:href => 'https://twitter.com/KeepItLocal', :data => {'show-count' => 'false', :size => 'large'}}
            Follow @KeepItLocal


-# footer
%div{:data => {:role => 'footer'}}
```